# How can I serve pre-compressed files from Cloud Run?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I'm using Cloud Run with a Node runtime. My static file server will serve gzip and brotli compressed files if they're present, so I've pre-generated them for all assets. Locally, this works great, but once deployed Cloud Run is stripping the content-encoding response header so that the browser misinterprets the response and renders junk.

I can't find any docs on header filtering with Cloud Run, but I found some on App Engine that indicate that it filters out the Accept-Encoding request header, and Content-Encoding response header. If this were the case I'd figure that my app would serve the uncompressed resource though.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: If you are using Cloud Run with Node ... what HTTP farmework are you using?  Express.js?  Cloud Run should "simply" route the incoming HTTP connection to your container listening app.  What your app returns in the headers is completely up to your app.  Does your app explicitly set headers for return?  Are you setting a header and not seeing it in the response?

Comment: I'm using Koa and koa-static. I verified with logs that koa-static is seeing the accept-encoding request header and setting the content-encoding response header, both locally and deployed to Cloud Run. Deployed however, the response headers in Chrome do not include content-encoding.

Comment: Here are the App Engine standard docs that mention removing accept-encoding and content-encoding headers: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/reference/request-response-headers

I can't find similar docs for Cloud Run. And I do see the accept-encoding header.

Comment: Well, I can't see how this isn't a bug, so I filed an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147185337

Comment: Hi, did you get any news on this issue from google ? I'm facing same problem ...